# Generate AR(1) process with different $y_0$ values in R

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive

I need to plot an AR(1) graph for the process 
$$
y_k = 0.75y_{k-1} + \varepsilon_k
$$
for $y_0=1$ and another graph for $y_0=10$. Assume $\varepsilon_k$ is uniformly distributed on interval $[-0.5,0.5]$.

I have the following code but I am not sure how to control $y_0$:

```
#----------#Start#---------#
rm(list=ls())
library(tseries)
#library(zoo)
set.seed(0)
y<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n=100, innov = runif(100, 0, 1))
y.1<-y-0.5
ts.plot(y.1)
```

Comment: It seems you are interested in R implementation, which would be off topic. Or do you have a generic statistical question on how to simulate AR(1) processes?

Answer (score 8):

`arima.sim` does not allow such fine control. But if you look at the function definition, you will notice that it is just applying `filter` to the innovations series. So you can do that directly, and make sure it starts where you want it to.

```
y0 <- 10
y.1 <- filter(c(y0,runif(99,-0.5,0.5)), 0.75, method='recursive')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to shift the whole series by the first value generated and then add your starting condition back in. Also, you can do `runif(100, -0.5, 0.5)` instead of subtracting a half like you have now. I think this makes it more readable.

```
y0 <- 10
y<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=.75), n=100, innov = runif(100, -0.5, 0.5))
y.1<-y - y[1] + y0
ts.plot(y.1)
```

Comment: That will make the process have mean `y0`  whereas the specified process should have mean 0.